# SOM what is the values for T1 and T2

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, som

I am implementing an SOM in matlab. For the decay of learning rate ,

> updated_learningrate = original_learningrate * exp(-t/T1)

and

> updated_sigma = original_sigma * exp(-t/T2)

What are the values to be given for T1 and T2? In all the text books and web tutorials I referred , it is just said that they are time constants. But they does not tell which range of values to use. Please help

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your model/scenario, there is no general answer. Try out different values. Inf is a constant learning rate.

To cover a huge range quickly, try a logarithmic scale. Something like `T=10.^(-4:4)`

Comment: same value for both T1 and T2? I tried wih various values and found that different values are best for different number of  training steps